# Seamlessly load images to ASP.NET page

Tags: asp.net, image, request

I've been trying to load an image onto an aspx page without revealing its request. I mean - when I monitor the page with Telerik's Fiddler I can see that the image is in the requests list. If I refresh the page, the request is not being shown anymore (apparently the image got cached the first time).

---

**Question:** Is it possible to load/cache the image silently, without the user even knowing it had been requested?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After a bunch of hours messing with various techniques involving requests, server side operations and what not, it turned out to be as simple as it can get..
In order to hide the image loading request I modified the previous page.
I have, for example, pages A and B. I need to cloak an image request for page B.
Page A loads a bunch of images already. Lets squeeze in one more? Image gets loaded and cached. When the user opens page B, image is still in cache and is used instead of requesting a new one. 
All we had to do was to put this

```
<img src="sampleImage.png" style="display:none" />
```

code in page A somewhere, so it got requested, loaded and cached, but not shown.
Too simple solution to be more embarrased than proud to solve, but this is how I learn, I guess :D

Comment: If you look with Fiddler, I think you'll see a request for that image, and that the request is resolved from cache. Certainly other tools will show you that. Also, nothing _requires_ the browser to cache the image. You cannot completely hide the fact that you need this image. If nothing else, the `<img>` tag exists in the page and can be seen via "View Source"

Comment: @JohnSaunders Yes, we can see the markup, but this is not the case. This time it is important, that we don't see the image request on page load

Comment: Also the `<img>` tag won't be visible because of `display:none`